# Navigate between Facelets and JSP pages

Tags: jsp, jsf, navigation, facelets

Is it possible to navigate between Facelets and JSP pages?

For example:

```
<h:commandLink ... action="goToJsp" />
```

And after

```
<h:commandButton .. action="returnToFacelets" />
```

Is there some incovenience?

I'd like this scenario because the JSTL XML taglib is only available in JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as those JSP pages are also served by the Faces Servlet, there should be no problem.